# 'System.IO.Directory' does not contain a definition for 'EnumerateFiles'

Tags: c#, .net

habe a problem, I developed a program with .NET 4 Framework but I have to switch to 3.5 (VS 2008) - but in 3.5 is EnumerateFiles not included. What I can use for this ?

I use it here:

```
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder_pfad, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12782/File-System-Enumerator-using-lazy-matching

Comment: You can use [`GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) if aren't required to lazy enumerate the directory.

Answer (score 5):

I think this will work...

```
s = Directory.GetFiles(folder_pfad, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```